# Using ActionBarSherlock Tabs inside an existing View or Layout in the current Activity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to make a swipe-able view with tabs using the ActionBarSherlock and I managed to do so, but I have some stuff that I want to show before the these tabs..

[image: on the left what I managed to do, on the right what I want to do]

I want to add these elements before the ActionBar tabs or view the whole SherlockFragmentActivity inside a relativeLayout below the upper header of a parent activity

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Can you please explain which elements are you trying to add?

Comment: I wan to add an app icon, a button with a dropdown menu and and a login button and I have them in a separate layout ..